# Tcl wasn't installed properly

Tags: python, pycharm

I am a new user using Pycharm to do simple test on turtle graphics.

```
import turtle as t
tu = t.Turtle()
for _ in range(15):
    tu.forward(5)
    tu.penup()
    tu.forward(5)
    tu.pendown()
```

However, when I run the codes, they turned out the following errors:

```
  ..._tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
{C:\Program Files (x86)\Tcl\lib\tcl8.3} {C:/Program Files (x86)/Tcl/lib/tcl8.6} C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/library C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/library C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/tcl8.6.9/library C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/tcl8.6.9/library
    
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Tcl/lib/tcl8.3/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.3
    version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.3
        while executing
    "package require -exact Tcl 8.3"
        (file "C:/Program Files (x86)/Tcl/lib/tcl8.3/init.tcl" line 19)
        invoked from within
    "source {C:/Program Files (x86)/Tcl/lib/tcl8.3/init.tcl}"
        ("uplevel" body line 1)
        invoked from within
    "uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Tcl/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.6
    version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.6
        while executing
    "package require -exact Tcl 8.6"
        (file "C:/Program Files (x86)/Tcl/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl" line 19)
        invoked from within
    "source {C:/Program Files (x86)/Tcl/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl}"
        ("uplevel" body line 1)
        invoked from within
    "uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"
    
    This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I've checked these file and folder exist. Can someone suggest me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a number of posts with the [same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=This%20probably%20means%20that%20Tcl%20wasn%27t%20installed%20properly.) perhaps you can find a solution if no one answers the question in the meanwhile.